# What to do when your question is not an unsolved problem but a bug

Tags: discussion

I have asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128077/android-opening-a-file-with-action-get-content-results-into-different-uris/36129285) question today and discovered that my question is not a problem but a bug of Android.

In the context of my question, I have tried to download a new file into the Downloads dir and this file was openable within my application without adjusting my code. My conclusion for my problem is that my code was valid but, I have encountered a bug in Android so my question is not a problem anymore.

I think answering my own question is not right because this is not the answer of my question. Adding a comment is not clear enough

How do I handle this situation?

Comment: Can you confirm it is a bug?  Is there a bug report?  If so then you can write an answer detailing why the bug stops the code from working and you can link to the bug report.  You could do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32784399/possible-bug-in-handling-the-default-keyword-in-vs2015-c) answer.

Comment: I can't confirm that this is a bug. I have searched about this 'bug' and did not found anything similar. I have tried to found out why I am facing this bug but could not found out why, neither could reproduce this problem. I also don't have much time to research about it.

Comment: *neither could reproduce this problem* There is a close reason for this: *This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.*

Comment: You would need to explain in a comment or edit to the question that you can't reproduce anymore though, since that's not apparent in the post right now.

Comment: There is an answer now with +3 score.

Comment: I have added a comment and edited my question. I think some people are misunderstanding me. It also could be my bad English. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first [search to see if your bug has been reported](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/advsearch).  If it has, it's fine to create an answer with a description of the bug and a link to the issue, as Nathan recommended.

- You don't necessarily have to accept your own answer, if the other answer was more helpful to work around any bug.

If you don't find an existing report, you could [file your own bug report](https://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html).

- If the report is closed, check the reason.  It will likely confirm that it's not an actual bug. Many suspected bugs turn out to be programmer errors.
- If the report is left open and (un)assigned, it's an actual bug.  Provide an answer as previously explained.

Since you don't have much time to research the issue:

- Make sure you're searching the right resource, such as an issue tracker.
- Make sure you're using the the right terms or keywords. Use specific error messages when possible, such as `FileNotFoundException`. There's currently only 58 open issues, so it wouldn't take much time to see if there's an existing report.

It really doesn't take that much time to search the right sites, such as an issues tracker or developer forum. The key is generally knowing where to search, and what to specifically search for, to turn up reports in the first place.

*As an aside, [my very first SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492749/why-does-a-labels-text-alignment-and-color-revert-to-default-values-after-reloa) turned out to be an iOS bug, and I ended up self-answering it with links to bug reports.*

Comment: I have created a new report for it: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=204636&thanks=204636&ts=1458571718